# MySQL - Database Security

Tags: mysql, database, security

I am creating a web application that collects a lot of personal information from each user, the type of thing that would potentially be hacked. What conventions and practices should I be aware of regarding database security? For example, should I make a separate MySQL user account with unique usernames and passwords for each user of the application, to prevent users from being able to retrieve others' information?

Comment: What sort of data are you looking to store? No you don't want separate MySQL user accounts for each user. A user shouldn't be accessing MySQL directly anyway. My guess is that based on the questions you asked, if you are trying to store credit card of social security data, that you might be best served to use a vault service rather than build something yourself.

Comment: What I mean is, while I'm not new to programming, I am new to website security, I don't know what practices are considered good and which are bad regarding leaving unnecessary security holes open.

Comment: The user isn't directly accessing MySQL, the web server accesses it to load the page, and it's accessed via Ajax to update the page continuously (the second part is a hopeful).

Comment: Well there is a difference between security at the database layer and security at the website layer.  This really is a non-trivial topic and not one you are going to get definitive answers for here in one question on SO.  A lot depends on the architecture of you application, the sort of data you are storing, your hosting solution, etc.

Comment: You may want to create separate user accounts for DB administration(high priviledge) and one account for use by the web application(only required priviledges). But a separate user account for every user is certainly not required. As @MikeBrant already pointed out that a user shouldn't be accessing MySQL anyway.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist You would never have an AJAX call going directly against the database. There would always be some intermediate web service which would authenticate and authorize users and interact with the database.

Comment: simple rule of thumb: you never EVER give end-users a direct login to the database. there's no need for it. your application should be the only thing logging into the DB, and it's your application that enforces security rules.

Comment: You can go through OWASP site for some good detailed information: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Stackoverflow could only point you to material relating security. There are various aspects from (+) not using root as db user, (+) using prepared SQL statements, (+) using encrypted, salted, and not MD5. For such things one need reading.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what sort of site you have in mind, it's difficult to recommend an appropriate level of risk management. Is the website collecting information relating to computer game players or private medical data?

Answer (score 3):

**Hardware level security**

Make sure the hardware is in a secure facility, preferably a facility with redundant power sources, backbone connections, etc.  The city I live in has a network of caves and there is a data center in there. The center has six distinct connections to the city power grid and is connected to multiple backbone providers – pretty cool.

**Application level security**

You'll want to use [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) in an effort to avoid SQL injection.  If you're using PHP I suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You'll also want to use "whitelisting" - only allowing values from a predefined list of valid values.  For instance, when allowing someone to enter a first name you might restrict valid characters to only be [a-zA-Z] (only upper and lower case letters).  Regular Expressions come in handy here.

You'll want to set up tables similar to this to handle security:

```
actions
    id          unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50) // Delete users, edit account, etc.

roles
    id          unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50) // Billing admin, web developer, etc.

roles_actions
    id          unsigned int(P)
    role_id     unsigned int(F roles.id)
    action_id       unsigned int(F actions.id)

users
    id          unsigned int(P)
    username        varchar(32)
    password        varbinary(255)
    …

users_roles
    id          unsigned int(P)
    user_id     unsigned int(F users.id)
    role_id     unsigned int(F roles.id)
```

This will allow an unlimited number of actions to be associated with each role and an unlimited number of roles to be associated with each user.  Makes it fairly easy to manage permissions amongst users.

If you're thinking about storing credit card information you'll want to do a lot of research first.  There are some serious issues surrounding that.

You might want to log every "visit" to a page for security reasons (IP address, user ID – NULL if it's someone who's not logged in, etc.)

You might want to maintain an audit trail of every change made to every table in your database(s).  Triggers can be handy for that.

**Database level security**

You'll want to follow the [Principle of Least Privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).  You'll also want to look into [Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html).

That's just some things off the top of my head.

Comment: Just read this - +1 from me.  Very good.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear: there should be one credential for the application to access the database, and others for individuals.  The individual would only provide the credentials authorize the user and to set up a session.  It wouldn't be used to manipulate the database.  That's the application's job.

Those should be role-based; users should be different from admins, and users should only see their own information.

All input should be validated and bound prior to persisting.  You don't want to suffer from SQL injection.

You'll want to encrypt, salt, and hash those passwords.

You might want to think about encrypting PII data in the database as well.

It's a big topic, not for the ignorant or faint of heart.  You need to do a lot more research than asking questions at SO.

Comment: Thank you, and I know, I took some books out of my local library. I plan on developing the application as I read, though, so I wanted a head start so I don't make obvious mistakes.